# How many LN is covered in one manga vol?

Tags: konosuba

I recently watched season 2 of Konosuba and now I want to carry on the story by reading. I was wondering how many LN vol 1 of the manga covered and if the manga is up to date with the anime. Should I read the light novel or buy the manga?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the light novel has 4 translated volumes (the fifth is slated for release on April 24th) and the manga has 5 (May 22nd for the sixth). The anime (two seasons) covers the first four volumes of the light novel and the first six of the manga-- so the anime has covered all translated material.

If you want to continue the story immediately, you can search for fan translations of the LN, although most translating groups don't do licensed content. Otherwise, you can wait for vol. 5 of the LN, or wait until fall when vol. 7 of the manga is released.

I would recommended starting over from the beginning with the LN, as the anime does skip some parts and you'll likely have to wait some time before reading new content either way.